# Grepping for exact string while ignoring regex for dot character

Tags: bash, grep

So here's my issue. I need to develop a small bash script that can grep a file containing account names (let's call it file.txt). The contents would be something like this:

```
accounttest
account2
account
accountbtest
account.test
```

Matching an exact line SHOULD be easy but apparently it's really not.

I tried:

```
grep "^account$" file.txt
```

The output is:

```
account
```

So in this situation the output is OK, only "account" is displayed.

But if I try:

```
grep "^account.test$" file.txt
```

The output is:

```
accountbtest
account.test
```

So the next obvious solution that comes to mind, in order to stop interpreting the dot character as "any character", is using fgrep, right?

```
fgrep account.test file.txt
```

The output, as expected, is correct this time:

```
account.test
```

But what if I try now:

```
fgrep account file.txt
```

Output:

```
accounttest
account2
account
accountbtest
account.test
```

This time the output is completely wrong, because I can't use the beginning/end line characters with fgrep.

So my question is, how can I properly grep a whole line, including the beginning and end of line special characters, while also matching exactly the "." character?

EDIT: Please note that I do know that the "." character needs to be escaped, but in my situation, escaping is not an option, because of further processing that needs to be done to the account name, which would make things too complicated.

Comment: You've shown several different outputs that you do not want, but what is the output you actually do want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`. `grep` also has the `-x` option which matches against whole lines only. You can combine these to get what you want:

```
grep -Fx account.test file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, camh!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The `.` is a special character in regex notation which needs to be escaped to match it as a literal string when passing to `grep`, so do

```
grep "^account\.test$" file.txt
```

Or if you cannot afford to modify the search string use the `-F` flag in `grep` to treat it as literal string and not do any extra processing in it

```
grep -Fx 'account.test' file.txt
```

From `man grep`

> `-F`, `--fixed-strings`
>
> Interpret `PATTERN` as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
>
> `-x`, `--line-regexp`
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  For a regular expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with `^` and `$`.

Comment: I probably should have specified this. I know it has to be escaped, but as I said, the contents of the file is variable and in my particular situation it would be difficult to escape it.

Comment: Quoting the dot has nothing to do with shell processing. It is not quoted "before passing to grep", but processed by grep itself. A dot is a special character in a regular expression so it needs to be quoted if you want to remove the special nature and use it literally.